# How do I use whenever?

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure as following sentence whether right or wrong?
"Please let me know whenever, if anything else suitable come up."

Comment: I'd phrase it as either *Please let me know if anything suitable comes up* or *Please let me know whenever something suitable comes up*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:** You expect suitable things to pop up from time to time, and you want to be notified of all of them.

*"Please let me know **whenever** anything suitable comes up."*

**Case 2:** You don't know if suitable things will pop up at all.  Maybe nothing suitable will ever come up.  If it does, you would like to be notified.

*"Please let me know **if** anything suitable comes up."*

**Case 3:** Similar to Case 2.  Now, though you expect that at least one suitable thing will occur, and you want to be notified right away when it does.

*"Please let me know **if and when** anything suitable comes up."*

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence, "Please let me know whenever, if anything else suitable come up", seems to suggest that you're saying to someone, "If anything else suitable comes up, let me know whenever you have time".
But if you're trying to say, "If anything else suitable comes up, let me know (right away)", then you'd be better saying, "Please let me know when anything else suitable comes up".